# _OBJC_CLASS Error Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I get the below error in my xcode console application. I Could not understand what is wrong in my code as the error is something different.
Please advise

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Vehicle",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Provide more details regarding what library you are trying t use. Share some code pls.

Comment: Issue is resolved by adding the extension of Vehicle class inside .m file instead of creating new extension file

Comment: Hi Wolverine, I created a seperate extension file for Vehicle and added the implementation of Vehicle inside that class. Now i removed the extension file and added the implementation and the extension inside.m file of vehicle which resolved the issue.

Comment: @Harish I guess the issue might be, earlier there might have both the headers Vehicle.h and VehicleExtenstion.h imported into some file. Just a guess. And now as you have merged the files, you have only single header import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to tweak your build settings to allow a 32-bit build.

1. Select your project file in the Project Navigator (the left sidebar).
2. Select your project's target (first entry under TARGETS in the panel
   that just came up)
3. Find the "Architectures" setting (make sure "All" is selected if you
   can't find "Architectures")
4. Change it from "Standard Architectures" to "Universal" (or explicitly "32-bit" if you prefer)

You should be able to build after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I created a seperate extension file for Vehicle and added the implementation of Vehicle inside that class. Now i removed the extension file and added the implementation and the extension inside.m file of vehicle which resolved the issue